# Stripe - ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: ecmascript-6, stripe-payments

```
import 'stripe';
```

I can't seem to import server side stripe.js npm package into a Lit-HTML PWA.

I get:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

If I try:

```
import {Stripe} from 'stripe';

The requested module '../../../node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js' does not provide an export named 'Stripe'
```

I'm learning vanilla JS so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you installed the package from NPM correctly using 'npm install stripe --save' documented here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

Comment: Yes, it's been installed properly

Comment: Have you tried using the exact line from the docs: "import Stripe from 'stripe';"??

Answer (score 1):

`stripe-node` is for server-side use, not for use in the client.  You'll want to use [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) to collect card details, etc and then user `stripe-node` - or one of [the other libraries](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries) - server-side to handle those parts.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that I can't import the server side package after installing it

Comment: LitElement is a client side library: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide this is not going to work how you expect it to.

If you were importing this into a server-side node application it would work, but browsers don't natively have `require()` which is most likely why this is failing.